# Does emergent dualism solve the problem of brain damage without resorting to interactionist dualism?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, dualism

Emergent dualism is a solution to the brain damage problem for substance dualism. It states that the mind is a substance that arises from certain configurations of matter (such as the brain). And when the brain is damaged, the mind is also affected since it depends on the configuration of the matter of the brain.

My question is, does this classify as interactionist dualism? Because it doesn't seem at first sight.

Answer (score 1):

All mind-body theories have to account for interaction between mind and body.  Interaction in, say neural identity theory -- is the problem of how the mental events are even related to the physical.

Emergence theories, whether property emergence or substance emergence -- will have to account for interaction.  They also will have to explain EMERGENCE, which is a second type of interaction.

So -- yes an emergent substance dualism would be an interactive dualism.

Answer (score 0):

If the mind arises from matter, then reality is still consisting of physicalism, just of a different kind: source physicalism.

Source physicalism does not deny mental states or non physical things. But it does state that any and all immaterial/non physical things **come from/before** and **depend** on the physical. Since the source of everything is still then physical, it seems apt to call it physicalism, not dualism.

Comment: The most explict advocacy of emergent substance dualism is Karl Popper's the Self and its Brain.  Yes, Popper's model is "source physical" with respect to mental phenomena.  There is actually not much distance between Popper and emergent physicalists on this subject -- whehter one calls mental a dependent state genrated by matter, or a separate substance genrated by matter, is mostly semantics.  The primery difference is that the mental is independently causal in Popper's model, and emergence physicalists often waffle on causal independence.

Comment: Popper holds that world 3, ideas, pre-exists the physical, and is independent of it.  This is therefore NOT "source physicalism".  Notably, none of Papineau https://www.davidpapineau.co.uk/uploads/1/8/5/5/18551740/papineau_in_gillett_and_loewer.pdf Stoljar  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R13R2OUNXMIN6H/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0415452635 or Melnyk https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1A8I0RTYJEDJM/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0521827116 consider that abstractions need to be emergent from matter to be a physicalist.  Therefore none are source physicalists.

Comment: There would be no ideas without the brain. There is not a single concept that isn’t ultimately thought of by a brain. It’s an experience in consciousness that is emergent from a brain process. There’s no way around this. Ideas may be epistemically TRUE without the brain. For example, 2+2=4 is knowledge. But it makes no sense to talk about the truthfulness of a proposition “existing”. The proposition only “exists” as an experience in consciousness that is sourced from the physical.

Comment: there you go again asserting things that are not true, and which you have not done even preliminary self check on.  Causation is an IDEA, and without it, physicalism would simply not work.  Same with logic, same with math, same with state sequencing, and time.  No humans or consciousness are involved in this core feature of our universe.  The majority of theoretical physicists now treat math as more "real" than physics.

Comment: Causation is not just an idea. It’s a term that represents physical things. That’s like saying a chair is an idea.

Comment: Really?  Causation is material?  Where is it?  What is its mass?  Why repeat such obviously false claims?

Comment: Causation refers to a physical process, not an object. By your logic, photosynthesis is not material because it’s not an object that has mass.

Comment: What is the property that makes a PROCESS physical?  Processes are by definition relational, and relations are by definition logic states.  Are you now claiming that logic is physical too?

Comment: A process that involves physical components is “physical” in a practical sense the same way a “chair” which is just a word and technically a concept is still “physical” in a practical sense since it refers to an actual material object.

Comment: Photosynthesis is no more material than chemistry is a chemical. Sure leaves, oxygen carbon dioxide are material but that's not what you're saying. What you're saying is there's no category difference between chemistry and chemical, between oxygen etc and photosynthesis. You can have your trivializing definitions if you feel good but don't then pretend you're asking real questions

Comment: Of course there’s a category difference but photosynthesis is a physical process referring to physical things. If “photosynthesis” is immaterial then so is a “chair” since a “chair” refers to a combination and rearrangement of atoms in a particular way